# Swift: UIView changed size when keyboard appears

Tags: swift, animation, uiview, keyboard, textfield

Update:

My View on the storyboard has a View which is 215 height and it can be swipe up to 400 height and also swiped down from 400 to 215.

This View has a View which is auto layout 0,0,0,0. In this view i load the xib file.

The xib file contains the arrowImage, UIView, "or" label, and 2 buttons.

The UIView in the xib contains the textFields and the Labels and the height of this is set to 0 because it should not be showed on start, only on swipe up.

Now on swipe up i resize the View in the storyboard to 400 and inside i resize the view from the nib which contains the Textfields.

The Problem now is, when i click into the textfield no matter which one. It resize the View in the storyboard back to 215 and i don't know why this happens.

Gif to see whats happens:

[GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uxf9n.gif)

Comment: Sorry, I've read this 4 times and still am not sure what's your view hierarchy and setup. Can you explain it better, so that is easier for us to understand? Which is the parent view for the view containing the textField? What's his initial size? What should be the final size? What should happen (simplified)? Is that when you tap on the textField the textFields should move up to make room for the keyboard so that both the keyboard and textFields should be visible at the same time?  ...just edit your answer, I'll check later when I'll have time.

Comment: Sure sry for this understandable post:

Comment: so i have in storyboard a View which resize from 215height to 400height when i swipe up and swipe down the same from 400 to 215.

Comment: ok comment is not good to explain i update my post

Comment: ok i solve the problem it was a constraint problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check your constrains, if you are using the assistant editor in your project you are likely to have this kind of problems. After seeing the gif that's the most I can say without checking the code but some solutions I propose are either changing the constrains when you click the textfield using a identifier for the specific constrains or removing the constrains and implementing everything by code.

Here's some code to give you an idea on how to update the constrains:

```
    view.constraints.forEach({r in

        //Here you check for the specific constrains
        //I suggest you naming similar constrains the same
        if r.identifier == "yourIdentifier" {

            //You change the constrain value
            r.constant = 6

        }

        //Update the view constrains
        view.updateConstraints()
    })
```

Hope this is your case!

Comment: ok i solve the problem it was a constraint problem :) thanks for the note that it can be something with the constraints ;)